# Has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, orm, relational-database, has-many, has-many-through

I made a relationship with the three models using `has_many :through`:

```
class Curriculum class < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :interests
    has_many :vacancies,: through => :interests
end

class Vacancy class < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :interests
   has_many :resumes,: through => :interests
end

class Interest < ActiveRecord:: Base

    belongs_to :vacancy
    belongs_to :curriculum
end
```

And to create curriculum and vacancy, I create them by administrative, i need to know how can i create the interest to the id of the vacancy, and how it will be logged on the system I have to get the id of it and make the relationship in creating a new bank interest. I wonder how I can program it to do so, and I wonder how the controller will get the create action, and what better way to do this.

Comment: I forgot to comment above but I'm new with Ruby on rails, please disconsider something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to read the whole ["Guide to Rails on Associations"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association), especially the part about `has_many :through`. Then check your schema if your db is migrated and contains for the table `interests` the necessary foreign keys to `curriculums` and `vacancies` called `curriculum_id` and `vacancy_id`.

If that is all in place, the following code will create the relationship between two objects:

```
@curr = Curriculum.find(1)
@vac = Vacancy.find(1)
@curr.interests << @vac
@curr.save
```

The last two lines creates an interest between `@curr` and `@vac` and store that on the database. So you should not use IDs and handle them directly, but work with objects instead.

The second part now is to provide a UI to allow the definition (and removal) of interests between curricula and vacancies. The base flow here is:

- You have one curriculum in focus.
- You have a link to add / remove curricula.
- The view that opens shows a list of possible vacancies, where every vacancy has a checkbox.
- By selecting (or deselecting) the check boxes, the IDs of the vacancies will be held in the params of the request sent to the controller.

See the (older) podcast [Railscast #52](http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes) how to do that in a similar context. Or see the example for [has_many :through with checkboxes](http://millarian.com/programming/ruby-on-rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/).

An alternative way would be to use JQuery autocomplete, and add so interests one-by-one. See the nice podcast [Railscast #258](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields?view=asciicast) which uses JQuery Tokeninput for that.

Comment: And how can I make a button to the time I click on it to generate a new interest???

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for:

[HABTM Checkboxes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes)

That's the best way to use an **Has and Belongs to many** association.